# console.log in pure React iOS app built with Cordova

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, cordova, console.log

Got assigned to a project that is built entirely in **React** (not **React Native**), but there's a branch off the main master branch which is used to do builds for **iOS** using **XCode and Cordova** and publishing in the App Store.

The project uses **Redux** and every action is logged to the console, which is fine for browsers, but it's hugely important to have access to the logs in dev mode, once the application is run in a simulator/iOS device.

So, my question is, how can I get access to these logs when I'm using the **iOS** Simulator?

Thanks in advance!

[link to logs in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nenzm.png)

Comment: You can view the logs in chrome. You shake the device to open the developer menu, or press `⌘D` in the iOS simulator. Then press `Enable remote debugging`, and then open `http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui` in your browser. You are using `React Native` if you are developing mobile applications. React Native still uses core React but ultimately it is React Native that is going to turn your javascript code into a mobile application. https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but like I said, the app is built entirely in React, not React Native. I know how to see logs in React Native apps. This app is solely built for the web, but at some point it has been decided that a specific branch will slightly modify some of the styles (e.g. make buttons bigger, etc.) to adapt it to iOS tablet devices and the builds will be made from there. I need a way to access the logs when I build the app in the iOS emulator.

Comment: I'm confused. You said, `which is used to do builds for iOS using XCode and publishing in the App Store`. If it's a web app you cannot publish it to the app store, and you cannot create builds for XCode, since a web app just html you simply open it in the web browser. In the case that your application is a web app, you should be able to see the logs in the servers console.

Comment: No, it's not a React Native app. I mentioned this 2 times already. I can run it locally in the browser, yes, but this is not my use case. I create a build using webpack, which is then built using cordova in XCode.

Comment: You should mention that you're using Cordova in your original post there's no way for anyone to help you if you do not mention which tools you are using. Anyways, at https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/next/ there is a section called `Safari Remote Debugging with Web Inspector` which is going to allow you to view  whatever logs you need.

Comment: @IsaacCWay thanks, you're right, I should've mentioned that I use Cordova. So, yes, basically, after you build the app, you need to launch the Safari Remote Debugger via Safari > Develop > [Device/Emulator] > [Name-of-your-app]

Answer (score 0):

The Cordova documentation has described the steps you need to take in such a situation and it's available for both Safari and Chrome (if you want to do some additional setup):

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/next/#safari-remote-debugging-with-web-inspector

So, basically, after you build the app, you need to launch the Safari Remote Debugger via Safari > Develop > [Device/Emulator] > [Name-of-your-app]